# XSLT Merge two same elements in one

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have been trying to merge two same elements under one using XSLT 2.0

Sample source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<summary>
<object>
    <para>Paragraph <ref>Test1.</ref>AAA</para>
    <para>Test2.</para>
</object>
<objects>
    <para>
        <title>Title 1</title>: (1) Testing1</para>
    <para>(2) Testing 2</para>
    <para>Testing 3</para>
</objects>
<objects>
    <para>
        <title>Title 2</title>: Testing 4</para>
</objects>
```

Desired output would be:

```
<summary>
<object>
    <para>Paragraph <ref>Test1.</ref>AAA</para>
    <para>Test2.</para>
</object>
<objects>
    <para>
        <title>Title 1</title>: (1) Testing1</para>
    <para>(2) Testing 2</para>
    <para>Testing 3</para>
    <para>
        <title>Title 2</title>: Testing 4</para>
</objects>
</summary>
```

I use the following template for the transformation unfortunately it is not giving me desired result..

```
<xsl:template match="summary">
    <xsl:for-each select="//objects">
        <xsl:element name="objects">
            <xsl:for-each select="//objects/*">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*|@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()"  >
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how the input can look and what you want to do for instance if the `summary` element has various `objects` elements that are not sibling elements (e.g. `<summary><object>..</object><objects>..</objects><object>...</object><objects>..</objects></summary>`), do you want to merge those `obects` elements as well or only adjacent siblings?

Comment: Yes i wanted to merge objects elements and you answer did the trick. Thank you so much Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to merge all `objects` sibling elements then

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="objects[1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node(), following-sibling::objects/node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="objects[position() gt 1]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

should suffice. For merging only adjacent siblings you could use `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::objects)">...</xsl:for-each-group>` in a template matching `summary` or any `objects` parent.